# Observations of harmonics in gravitational wave experiments

Tags: gravitational-waves, harmonics

In gravitational wave astronomy, we usually observe $f_{GW}=2f_K$ (gravitational wave frequency twice the orbital frequency from keplerian motion). However, we also know there should be harmonics with $f=nf_0$. How could these harmonics be observed in usual GW detections?

Comment: What is $f_0$ supposed to mean?

Comment: $f_0=f_{GW}$, so $f=nf_0$ means a multiple of fundamental frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The gravitiational wave strain obeserved from a compact binary depends on the direction from which the event is observed. More precisely if $h_{+}$ is the observed "plus" polarization and $h_{\times}$ the "cross" polarization these are conventianally combined in a "complex" strain variable $h = h_{+} - i h_{\times}$. The strain $h$ is a variable of time $t$, the luminonsity distance $D_L$, and the viewing angles of the obserever $\theta_{\rm obs}$ and $\phi_{\rm obs}$. (For a distant observer) This dependence can be decomposed as

$$ h(t,D_L,\theta_{\rm obs},\phi_{\rm obs}) = \frac{1}{D_L} \sum_{\ell=2}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\ell}^{+\ell} h_{\ell m }(t) {_{-2}Y_{\ell m}}(\theta_{\rm obs},\phi_{\rm obs}),$$

where the ${_{-2}Y_{\ell m}}(\theta_{\rm obs},\phi_{\rm obs})$ are [spin-weighted spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-weighted_spherical_harmonics) with spin-weight $-2$, and the $h_{\ell m}(t)$ are called the harmonic modes of the gravitational waveform. For quasi-circular binaries in which all spins are aligned with the orbital angular momentum, the frequency of each $h_{\ell m}(t)$ is given by $m f_{\rm orb}$, where $f_{\rm orb}$ is the orbital frequency of the binary.

The gravitational waveform of a typical binary is dominated by the $\ell=|m|=2$ modes, which is why you will often see the claim that "the" frequency of the gravitational waves is two times the orbital frequency. However, generally speaking many harmonic modes will be present in any observed signal, which will contribute different multiples of the orbital frequency to the spectrum. Note that these are note necessarily multiple of the dominant 22-mode frequency. For example, the $\ell=2$ $m=1$ mode has *half* the frequency of the $\ell=|m|=2$ mode. Nonetheless, in the lingo of the field all modes that are not the $\ell=|m|=2$ mode are referred to as "higher modes".

The relevance of the "higher modes" depends a lot on the properties of the binary. In particular, binaries with asymmetric mass-ratios, high-spin, high total mass, and that are viewed "edge-on" have much stronger higher-modes than equal mass-non-spinning binaries, viewed "face on" (the propeties of the spin-weighted spherical harmonics imply that from face on, only the $m=2$ are observable).

To get back to the question of how these higher harmonics can/are observed, we must first look at how gravitational waves are observed in the first place. We observe gravitational waves by comparing the strain measured by our detectors (e.g. by LIGO, Virgo, or KAGRA) to theoretical predictions of what the gravitational waves from a binary should look like. By finding the best match, we can then infer the properties of the source. The more accurate the theoretical model, the more accurate these measurement can be.

The theoretical models used for the first observations of gravitational waves contained only the the $\ell=|m|=2$ modes, which for example meant that we couldn't really measure the observation angle $\theta_{obs}$, because it was completely degenerate with the luminousity distance $D_L$, (this also meant that we had very large uncertainties on the luminousity distance). Later iterations of the used waveform models, such as SEOBNRv4HM, added the higher modes ("HM") to the model as well, which allowed more accurate measurements of various properties of the binaries. The first observation for which this improvement has been documented in detail is [GW170729](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06742). From the  abstract:

> We find no indication of spin-precession, but the inclusion of higher-order modes in the models results in an improved estimate for the mass ratio of (0.3–0.8) at the 90% credible level. Our updated measurement excludes equal masses at that level. We also find that models with higher-order modes lead to the data being more consistent with a smaller effective spin, with the probability that the effective spin is greater than zero being reduced from 99% to 94%. The 90% credible interval for the effective spin parameter is now (-0.01-0.50). Additionally, the recovered signal-to-noise ratio increases by ∼0.3 units compared to analyses without higher-order modes; ***the overall Bayes factor in favor of the presence of higher-order modes in the data is 5.1∶1***.
> (with emphasis added). The therefor find substantial evidence that higher modes are indeed present in the signal.

The latest generation of waveform models used for the ongoing observation run of the LIGO-Virgo-KAGRA collaboration such as [SEOBNRv5PHM](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.18046), [IMRPhenomXPHM](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.06503), and [IMRPhenomTPHM](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.05872), all include higher modes with  SEOBNRv5PHM containing the $(2,\pm2)$, $(2,\pm1)$, $(3,\pm3)$, $(3,\pm2)$, $(4,\pm4)$, $(4,\pm3)$, and $(5,\pm5)$ modes (and the others subsets thereof).